# SQLite comparing time values

Tags: sqlite

I've got a time field (HH:MM:SS) in a table and need a query that limits results to all records where the time field is more than 3:00:00

Pretty sure I need to use the time() function somehow, but no matter what I try I either get an error or incorrect resultsets.

```
select * from table where time_happens > '03:00:00'
```

...doesn't give an error, but doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Try `> time(03:00:00)`

Comment: I get an error. Time argument as a string gets no error, but it returns records with a time of 1:00:12

Comment: Are the fields really in format `HH:MM:SS`, is the hour always two digits long?

Comment: Ah! No the format can be H:MM:SS. How does that change things? Is it actually a string even though the SQLite field is DATETIME?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You noted that the values can sometimes be stored without the leading zero (e.g. `1:00:12`). This creates problems.

SQLite does not have special date/time data types. It allows date/time values to be stored in the basic types like `TEXT` ([more info](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime)), but then it expects them to be in one of the [predefined formats](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) only. There is `HH:MM:SS` in the list, but no `H:MM:SS`, so it would never understand your values, even if you used some date/time functions:

```
sqlite> SELECT TIME('12:34:56');
12:34:56
sqlite> SELECT TIME('2:34:56');
```

But you don't actually need to make SQLite understand your values here. If you pad them correctly (when inserting, by an `UPDATE`, or dynamically during the `SELECT`), it will work even without using any functions, because plain string comparisons are enough:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE SUBSTR('0'||time_happens,-8,8) > '03:00:00';
```

Note I needed to use the [SQLite padding workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899832/sqlite-function-to-format-numbers-with-leading-zeroes).
Also you will still get the unpadded values in the result.

Comment: Thanks, Yirka! I will tighten up my formatting before the insert to sort this "datetime".