# SQLite concatenation

Tags: string, sqlite, datetime, sql-update, concatenation

```
UPDATE table 
SET [Date] = SUBSTR([Date], -4) || '-' || (CAST([Date] AS INT)) || '-' ||
             (CAST(SUBSTR([Date], INSTR([Date], '/') + 1) AS INT))
```

I'm trying to use the above SQLite query to take a date string in the `MM/DD/YYYY` format and change it to `yyyy-mm-dd`.  It's written the way it is to account for the various ways this particular date format can appear (i.e. `M/D/YYYY`, `M/DD/YYYY` and `MM/D/YYYY`)

If I only take 2 segments of the above query (so the month and year, year and day, or day and month), it works. However, when I try to concatenate the entire query above, something breaks and I just get the original date string.

Any idea what is happening?

Thanks,

Edited to clarify

Answer (score 1):

You can use string functions like that:

```
update mytable 
set date = substr(date, -4) || '-' || substr(date, 1, 2) || '-' || substr(date, 4, 2)
```

Comment: That unfortunately won't work due to how the dates can appear (months and days with only one digit).  I've edited my above post to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Consider incorporating [zero-pad solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4899832/1422451) with `PRINTR` or `SUBSTR('00'...)` with some nested wrangling for day part:

```sql
UPDATE myTable
SET date = SUBSTR(date, -4)   || '-' || 
           PRINTF('%02d', SUBSTR(date, 1, INSTR(date, '/')-1)) || '-' ||  
           PRINTF('%02d', REPLACE(SUBSTR(date, INSTR(date, '/')+1, 2), '/', ''));
```

```sql
UPDATE mytable 
SET date = SUBSTR(date, -4)   || '-' || 
           SUBSTR('00'||SUBSTR(date, 1, INSTR(date, '/')-1), -2) || '-' ||  
           SUBSTR('00'||REPLACE(SUBSTR(date, INSTR(date, '/')+1, 2), '/', ''), -2);
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5Ljv2Vzpxb1J87yKmziXey/1)</kbd>